# Join text + variable in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In Razor how do i print some text + a variable value ?

eg :

```
@for(int i=0;i<5;i++)                      
{
  <input type="text" value="@i" id = "name_@i"/>
}
```

the above code prints id = "name_@i", but i want the value of i in the id tag.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@for(int i=0;i<5;i++)                      
{
  <input type="text" value="@(i)" id = "name_@(i)"/>
}
```

When you're having trouble getting Razor to understand your intent, use parenthesis around your expression to create an "[Explicit Expression](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)."

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to insert variable in Razor view, insert variable at any where just wrap your variable to (XXX)

```
  <div data-original-title="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="@(identifier)completeicon"></div>
  <div data-original-title="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="comple@(identifier)teicon"></div>
  <div data-original-title="user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="completeicon@(identifier)"></div>
```